# Install two sets of different graphic card drivers

Tags: drivers, gpu

So this is temporary but I need to use both on-board and dedicated GPU but the latest AMD Omega Drivers don't work with my on-board GPU since it's older. It is possible to install two different sets of drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot install two sets of drivers that are for the same product, from the same vendor, and use the same driver name. You will have to choose between either the onboard (old) GPU and the dedicated (new) GPU.

However, you could try rolling back to the old compatible drivers and see if that still works with your dedicated GPU.